# xsl xml "transformation count"

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, transformation

We are using a product (Axway API Gateway) that is doing an XML (SOAP) to JSON transformation via XSL.  The problem is we are hitting an "XPath transformation limit".  We've increased the limit in the product which works for a while, until we end up getting a larger XML response which breaks it again.

The question is not really about the product but rather if anyone knows of a tool that we could leverage that would help us understand how the xsl is performing the transformation with data that might help us reduce the resultant xpath transformations/complexity that seems to be the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The XPath/XSLT specifications do not prescribe *how* to perform a transformation; they only specify what the result needs to be. The terms "transformation count" or "transformation limit"  are completely meaningless outside the scope of the product you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I rely on [Oxygen Developer](https://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_developer.html) (no affiliation). Also great for [profiling](https://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_developer/xslt_debugger.html).